# Expression {{current_username()}} is not being read properly by Superset row level security with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, apache-superset

I have been trying to add Row Level Security to Superset and I have written this clause:

[image: rls clause]

when I hard code this clause in a select on the database it works as it should but when I try to dynamically call current_username() it does not read it properly.

This is what happens when I call current_username() on sqlLab:

[image: sqlLab result]

I am currently using Superset 0.999.0dev on docker, and I am connecting to a Postgres Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Basically what you need to do is follow [this guide](https://apache-superset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) to get the docker image directly from github.

Once you have cloned the project, find the folder where the project is saved and look for docker/pythonpath/superset_config.py and, inside this file, place `"ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING":True` inside `FEATURE_FLAGS` like [so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAhGc.png).

Once you are done editing the file you should be able to run the docker-compose command. FYI, it takes a little while to fully load.